# Namespace vs regular package

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

What's the difference between a namespace Python package (no `__init__.py`) and a regular Python package (has an `__init__.py`), especially when `__init__.py` is empty for a regular package?

I am curious because recently I've been forgetting to make `__init__.py` in packages I make, and I never noticed any problems.  In fact, they seem to behave identically to regular packages.

Edit: Namespace packages only supported from Python 3.3 ([see PEP 420](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)), so naturally, this question only applies to Python 3.

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

### Namespace packages

As of [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages), we get namespace packages. These are a special kind of package that allows you to unify two packages with the same name at different points on your Python-path. For example, consider path1 and path2 as separate entries on your Python-path:

```
path1
+--namespace
   +--module1.py
   +--module2.py
path2
+--namespace
   +--module3.py
   +--module4.py
```

with this arrangement you should be able to do the following:

```
from namespace import module1, module3
```

thus you get the unification of two packages with the same name in a single namespace.

If either one of them gain an `__init__.py` that becomes **the** package - and you no longer get the unification as the other directory is ignored.

If both of them have an `__init__.py`, the first one in the PYTHONPATH (`sys.path`) is the one used.

### `__init__.py` used to be required to make directory a package

Namespace packages are packages without the `__init__.py`.

For an example of a simple package, if you have a directory:

```
root
+--package
   +--file1.py
   +--file2.py
   ...
```

While you could run these files independently in the `package` directory, e.g. with `python2 file1.py`, under Python 2 you wouldn't be able to import the files as modules in the root directory, e.g.

```
import package.file1
```

would fail, and in order for it to work, you at least need this:

```
package
  +--__init__.py
  +--file1.py
  +--file2.py
  ...
```

`__init__.py` initializes the package so you can have code in the `__init__.py` that is run when the module is first imported:

```
run_initial_import_setup()
```

provide an `__all__` list of names to be imported,

```
__all__ = ['star_import', 'only', 'these', 'names']
```

if the package is imported with the following:

```
from module import *
```

or you can leave the `__init__.py` completely empty if you only want to be able to import the remaining .py files in the directory.

#### Namespaces with `__init__.py` using pkgutil:

You could originally use [pkgutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html), available since Python 2.3. to accomplish adding namespaces, by adding the following into each separate package's `__init__.py`:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Setuptools uses a similar method, again, all `__init__.py` files should contain the following (with no other code):

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
```

Namespaces were more thoroughly addressed in  [PEP 420](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)

See also more discussion on setuptools and Namespaces here:

http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#namespace-packages

Comment: You mention that "While you can run these files independently in the package directory, e.g. with python file1.py, or python3 file1.py, you won't be able to import the files as modules in the root directory" - I am able to import a file as module in root directory - I am using python 3.6 - can you clarify if your answer is specific to an older version of python please?

Comment: @variable thanks for bringing this one to my attention, please review it and let me know if you think anything is missing?

Comment: I am a bit confused - you have the tree structure: root +--package   +--file1.py   +--file2.py, and then you do "import module.file1" and say it doesn't work. Did you mean "import package.file1" wouldn't work? Where does the name "module" come from at this point?

Comment: @Chachni thanks for pointing that out, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 7):

Reading [link](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#namespace-packages) from Aaron, and [PEP420](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), it appears that the fundamental difference between a namespace package and a regular package, beside the obvious difference that a regular package may contain various initialization code in `__init__.py`, is that a namespace package is a virtual package whose contents can be distributed in various places along Python's lookup path.

For example, given

```
a/foo/bar.py
b/foo/baz.py
```

If both `b` and `a` are in Python's path, you can import `foo.bar` and `foo.baz` freely.

Of course, this begs the question that, if `__init__.py` is not needed, then all other things being equal, is it better to make a regular package or a namespace package, but is a little off-topic.

Answer (score -8):

1. Having `__init__.py` makes it so you can import that package elsewhere.
2. Also, the `__init__.py` file can contain code you want executed each time the module is loaded.