# Coverage.py does not discover tests without init.py file in sub directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, init, coverage.py

When I run coverage for python, I always need an empty `__init__.py` file in the tests sub-directory to get coverage to run the tests. This is a requirement for python2 packages, but not for python3. To reproduce, I did the following (pre-requisites are python3, pip3 and brew):

1. Run the following terminal command:

   ```
   pip3 install coverage
   ```
2. Create the following directory structure:

   ```
   example\
       example.py
   tests\
       test_example.py
   ```

example.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
class Example:
    value = 3

    def update(self):
        self.value = 4
```

test_example.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unittest
from example.example import Example

class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        example_object = Example()
        self.assertEqual(3, example_object.value)
        example_object.update()
        self.assertEqual(4, example_object.value)
```

3. Run the following terminal command:

   ```
   coverage run --branch -m unittest discover -s . && coverage report
   ```

I should get: `Ran 1 test in x.yz seconds`, but I always get `Ran 0 tests in x.yz seconds`, and to fix this, I have to add `__init__.py` files to both directories. How can I run coverage without needing the init files?

Please let me know if you need anything else from me regarding this question. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Python 3 doesn't need `__init__.py` files, omitting them creates namespace packages, which are not a good idea if you don't need them.  For example, they are read last, so even directories later in the PYTHONPATH can shadow your files.

You should create the `__init__.py` files anyway.

Comment: Eventually, I would want to add more directories to the structure indicated in  2, like example2/example2SubDir/example2.py, and example3/example3.py. I would also add test files for these. Based on what I read about namespace packages, and this particular comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21819733/5560776

it seems like I would need to add the init files for my example, correct?

Comment: The best practice is to put an `__init__.py` file into any directory you want to be able to import.

Answer (score 1):

The exact path to the tests folder from the top has to be specified.
 For example:'python3 -m unittest discover src/main/python/tests'

Its most likely a bug with 'unittest discovery' where discovery works when you explicitly specify namespace package as a target for discovery.

But it does not recurse into any namespace packages inside namespace_pkg. So when you simply run 'python3 -m unittest discover' it doesn't go under all namespace packages (basically folders) in cwd.

Some PRs are underway(for example:[issue35617](https://bugs.python.org/issue35617)) to fix this, but are yet to be released