# Pytest-cov does not consider a file for coverage analysis unless it is imported in one of the unit tests?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-cov

I have 2 files in my project (`a.py` and `b.py`). `a.py` file is imported in the unit test file (`test_prog.py`) and there are tests written for it. Pytest-cov shows the coverage for this file.

However for the other file `b.py` - it is not seen in the code coverage output. Pytest-cov does not consider a file for coverage analysis unless it is imported in one of the unit tests?

Comment: Are you using the `--cov` argument?

Comment: Yes `--cov=folder_name` where `folder_name` is a folder that contains the files on which I want to get code coverage analysis.

Comment: Hm, works without problems for me (pytest-5.4.2). Maybe these are files in subdirectories without an `__init__.py`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The issue usually lies in early importing modules (before the coverage plugin was loaded).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen - Yes it happens when there is no `__init__.py` file. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coverage.py does not discover tests without init.py file in sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640812/coverage-py-does-not-discover-tests-without-init-py-file-in-sub-directories)

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered the same issue.

After a quick search, I've found that you have to lay out `__init__` structure in your source folder to be able to collect in the coverage report those files that are not being tested.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) for more about `__init__` files.

Comment: Good point, this is also commented on https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cov/issues/88

Comment: Still seeing source files not included as zero coverage if not exercised by test cases, even with a `__init__`.  However since we are "blind" to the project, we have to use `--cov=.` with `PYTEST_ADDOPT` - which may have be insufficient?

Comment: Same issue, I had `__init__.py` in my folders, but it still wasn't being picked up in coverage. even with the `include_namespace_packages` option being set. 
Turns out I was using `--cov` which seems like it only picks up imported files actually imported in tests, and fixed it by using `--cov=.`

Answer (score 0):

For people also ending here, there is the solution: set `include_namespace_packages` to true *(pytest>=7.0.0)*

add a config file `.coverage_rc` for your pytest-cov command
ex: `pytest --cov=<folder> --cov-config=.coverage_rc`

Content of `.coverage_rc`

```
[report]
include_namespace_packages = true

# might also be convenient to add one of these:
omit = **/__init__.py
skip_empty = true
```

Adapt the heading to `[tool.coverage.report]` if within a pyproject.toml file