# Pytest-Cov Show Coverage For Untouched Files

Tags: unit-testing, pytest-django, pytest-cov

When I run my tests, I realised that `pytest-cov` only shows coverage reports for files that are touched during the automated tests. How can I set it so that it shows coverage for even files that are not touched?

Comment: Oh wow, I came here using Google top result having the same question... surprised to see zero upvotes and answers. 

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62018120/pytest-cov-does-not-consider-a-file-for-coverage-analysis-unless-it-is-imported

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue.
Make sure you have a `__init__.py` file in every subdirectory (package).

More info: [why you want `__init__.py` files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804718/1254292).

My `pyproject.toml` file for reference:

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = [
    "--cov=mypackage",
    "--cov-report=term-missing",
]
```

output:

```
Name                                           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/mypackage/__init__.py                          4      0   100%
src/mypackage/sub/__init__.py                      0      0   100%
src/mypackage/sub/mod1.py                         23     23     0%   1-33
src/mypackage/sub/mod2.py                         41     41     0%   1-61
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. However, I would prefer a solution without __init__.py files. Only adding them for the purpose of test coverage seems to be weird.