# Python: accessing __init__.py function from within package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

I am trying to find a way to define a log function inside the `widgets/__init__.py` file which I can then use in the subpackages.

Currently I have this filestructure:

```
app.py
widgets/__init__.py
widgets/input/__init__.py
widgets/input/input.py
```

Contents of app.py:

```
import widgets

widgets.input.create_foo()
```

Contents of `widgets/__init__.py`:

```
from .input import input

def foo():
    print('foo')
```

Contents of `widgets/input/input.py`:

```
from .. import foo

def create_foo():
    foo()
```

If I run it like this I get the error 'ImportError: cannot import name 'foo' from 'widgets' from `widgets/__init__.py`. Which makes total sense because I try to import a function that is not created yet.

I would like to avoid creating a separate module or sub-package for just this 1 function.
Is there a clean way to define the 'foo()' function inside of `widgets/__init__.py` that can be used in sub-packages? What am I doing wrong here?

The reason why I want to do it like this is because I want to have a log function that I can use everywhere in the sub-packages without having to recreate it in every sub-package. 
I'm still very new to the whole package thing so please don't roast me to hard :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__.py` is not necessary. From python 3.3 every python file is a [namespace package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819649/namespace-vs-regular-package). Also, relative imports might be tricky. I suggest absolute imports approach:

```
.
├── app.py
└── widgets
    ├── input
    │   ├── input.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    ├── __pycache__
    └── utils.py
```

app.py:

```
from widgets.input.input import create_foo

create_foo()
```

input.py:

```
from widgets.utils import foo

def create_foo():
    foo()
```